# Disallowed characters while passing cookies to a PHP site

Tags: php, perl, cookies

I am writing a perl program to get the content of one website. while passing cookie in the request, the response i am getting is **Disallowed Key Characters.**. The webpage, i am trying to get the content of, is designed using PHP. Is there any other way of passing cookies in a clean manner and get the content of the page,same as the browsers do?
The perl snippet is as follows:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $link);
$req->header("Host" => "www.example.com/sms");
$req->header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');
$req->header("Accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
$req->header("Accept-Language" => "en-us,en;q=0.5");
$req->header('Referer' => 'www.example.com/sms');
$req->header("Cookie" => 'ci_session=a:15:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"6a023126d470b5c23231f38b00be945f";s:10:"ip_address";s:14:"122.165.230.17";s:10:"user_agent";s:76:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0";s:13:"last_activity";i:1402922915;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:1:"u";s:7:"username";s:2:"id";s:2:"47";s:7:"uidtype";s:1:"0";s:2:"to";s:0:"";s:4:"from";s:0:"";s:6:"userid";s:0:"";s:3:"fto";s:0:"";s:5:"ffrom";s:0:"";s:12:"sendcontacts";s:0:"";s:6:"checks";s:0:"";}4bdd1a196f5e2fff297cbc0333fde8be');
$req->header("Connection" => "keep-alive");
my $res = $usragt->request($req);
my $code = $res->code();
my $content = $res->content();
print "\n<p>$content</p>\n";
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Disallowed Key Characters.s:32:"6a023126d470b5c23231f38b00be945f"</p>
```

Comment: Maybe curl via the command line is an option for you.

Comment: why are you sending that much data back in the cookie? A lot of that stuff looks ike it should NOT be roundtripped through the client, and/or is redundant, like the useragent string. That sort of thing should be stored in the server-side session, and the ONLY data you send out in the cookie is the session ID.

Comment: Have you tried using Codeigniter's input class to pass the cookie?

Comment: Hi Brett, I am just trying to design a client-side script to get the content of the website. Codeigniter is a server-side web framework

Answer (score 0):

I was going to put this in a comment since it's not really an *answer*, but it's too long:

I'm looking at the structure of your *cookie*, and it's a bit suspicious looking. Here's the breakdown of that cookie:

```
ci_session=a:15:
{
    s:10:"session_id";
    s:32:"6a023126d470b5c23231f38b00be945f";
    s:10:"ip_address";
    s:14:"122.165.230.17";
    s:10:"user_agent";
    s:76:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11;Ubuntu;Linux x86_64;rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0";
    s:13:"last_activity";
    i:1402922915;
    s:9:"user_data";
    s:0:"";
    s:1:"u";
    s:7:"username";
    s:2:"id";
    s:2:"47";
    s:7:"uidtype";
    s:1:"0";
    s:2:"to";
    s:0:"";
    s:4:"from";
    s:0:"";
    s:6:"userid";
    s:0:"";
    s:3:"fto";
    s:0:"";
    s:5:"ffrom";
    s:0:"";
    s:12:"sendcontacts";
    s:0:"";
    s:6:"checks";
    s:0:"";
}
4bdd1a196f5e2fff297cbc0333fde8be');
```

That last line **could** be cookie data, but the rest looks like something else. Cookies are bits of data that point to a unique ID set by the server. They usually have a *name* and a *value* associated with it.

The purpose of a cookie is to identify the browser that had previously visited the site. HTTP has no state, and cookies could help establish a state. For example, if you visit a store, a cookie could be set to represent your personal shopping cart. The items you buy won't be stored in the cookie -- only the cart ID. This way, the server can recognize you as you move around the store.

A cookie could contain an id that recognizes you as a user. For example, I log into a site, and check the *keep me logged in* box. A cookie is set to identify my user ID. When I return to the site, the site sees the cookie that's associated with a particular ID and skips the login process.

The point is that cookies themselves are usually short and sweet. Maybe 64 characters at the most. They may have an expiration date associated with it. Your *cookie* doesn't look like this. It's long, it's complex, and it contains a lot of stuff that are other parts of a header. I see IP address, Session_ID, User Agent, and what looks like some sort of query in that string. Much of it would change from system to system, so it'd make a terrible cookie.

Did you check the return status code from that webpage? I wouldn't be surprised if it was a `200` OK code. If that's the case, it means you've successfully contacted the server, and talked to that PHP page. It's the PHP page that's sending you back the *error*.

Since it's in the `session_id`, it could be that it's an invalid Session ID. Or, it could be almost anything else. You're talking to a PHP program, and it's hard to say what the error could possibly mean in that case.

You may need to find out how to chat with this webpage you want to talk to. Find out exactly the headers you need. Using `curl`could help. You can play around with the `--data` headings and see what's going on.

Sorry I can't give you a better answer than this.